# solidity function works perfectly in remix but in react application it is not executing in the same way

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs, react

**in Remix i execute it and it works as i expecting and when i check the value from other function it returns the expecting value**

```
function makeadmin(string memory cityN, address adminAdress, string memory AdminName, 
string memory hash) public
    {
        require(msg.sender==0x20db1A3eD27EEF75BEBb000961d07AD47Bf58197);

        require(!(ch[cityN].AAdminAdress==adminAdress ));
         require(!(adminscitystatus[cityN]));
        require(!(adminsaddressstatus[adminAdress]));

        ch[cityN].CCityName=cityN;
        ch[cityN].AAdminAdress=adminAdress;
        ch[cityN].AAdminName=AdminName;

        ch[cityN].hashh=hash;
          ch[cityN].noofadmins.push(adminAdress);
        ch[cityN].adminsid[adminAdress]=ch[cityN].noofadmins.length-1;
      adminscitystatus[cityN]=true;
        adminsaddressstatus[adminAdress]=true;
        cityforcompany.push(cityN);
        uint comid=cityforcompany.length-1;
        companycityid[cityN]=comid;
    }
```

**In React js it is not adding the value to respective variables in solidity contract and the variable res returns something like Result[] __proto__.constructor with 0 length**

```
async SubmitData4 (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      await window.ethereum.enable();
      var Acc= await web3.eth.getAccounts();


      console.log('acc',Acc);


      var res= await LandAbi.methods.makeadmin("muree","0x8057450DFC37633CF19fbaC32E1eF30E44B36007","muneeb","sdasere4e4fre").call({from: Acc[0]});

console.log("res",res);


}
```

Comment: You seem to have "found" the mistake one hour after I explained it in the answer below. How about accepting that answer then???

Comment: sorry brother your help is appreciative and your answer also give me information about orignal issue  i donot mean it i just write it after posting question may be internet issue but your answer is good

Comment: Since my answer has given you "information about original issue", you should accept it - by clicking on the V next to it. Instead, you posted that you found the issue, and then described exactly what had been explained in my answer prior to your findings. This description by itself shows that my answer has done more than giving you "information about original issue".

Comment: i don't know why you are not believing me okey for you i'm going to delete that comment but i also apologise to you if i hurt you

Comment: Did not hurt, and it's perfectly OK to add comments to your own question. But it is also custom to accept an answer which has answered your question, and according to that comment of yours, it did.

Comment: i will do it in future i'm also new to this community before this i did'nt know after getting answer you should click tick icon thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In order to actually execute the transaction, change `call` to `send`
2. The value returned to the off-chain is the receipt of the transaction

Comment: thanks brother your help really means alot to me